# How to change GitHub Actions OS from MacOs to Windows or Ubuntu?

Tags: r, yaml, github-actions

I'm currently using the macOs os version for my Github Actions but it's very consuming on my minutes thresholds as it has a 10x cost on the monthly limit

I would like to switch to Ubuntu or Windows but I'm not quite sure about how to change my YML file.

Here is my actual YML file of one of my workflow:

```
# Hourly scraping
name: amazonR Polite Price Checker

# Controls when the action will run.
on:
  schedule:
    - cron: '0 0 * * 1,4'

jobs:
  autoscrape:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: macos-latest

    # Load repo and install R
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@master
    - uses: r-lib/actions/setup-r@master

    # Set-up R
    - name: Install packages
      run: |
        R -e 'install.packages("tidyverse")'
        R -e 'install.packages("tibble")'
        R -e 'install.packages("openxlsx")'
        R -e 'install.packages("gdata")'
        R -e 'install.packages("lubridate")'
        R -e 'install.packages("rvest")'
        R -e 'install.packages("stringr")'
        R -e 'install.packages("dplyr")'
        R -e 'install.packages("purrr")'
        R -e 'install.packages("plyr")'
        R -e 'install.packages("polite")'
        R -e 'install.packages("xml2")'
        R -e 'install.packages("gt")'
        R -e 'install.packages("blastula")'
            
    # Run R script
    - name: Scrape with the polite package
      env:
          EMAIL_SENDER: ${{ secrets.EMAIL_SENDER }}
          EMAIL_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.EMAIL_PASSWORD }}
          EMAIL_RECIPIENT: ${{ secrets.EMAIL_RECIPIENT }}
          EMAIL_CC_1: ${{ secrets.EMAIL_CC_1 }}
          EMAIL_CC_2: ${{ secrets.EMAIL_CC_2 }}
          EMAIL_CC_3: ${{ secrets.EMAIL_CC_3 }}
      
      run: Rscript polite_price_checker.R

    # Add new files in data folder, commit along with other modified files, push
    - name: Commit files
      run: |
        git config --local user.name github-actions
        git config --local user.email "actions@github.com"
        git add polite_price/*
        git commit -am "GH ACTION Autorun POLITE PRICE $(date)"
        git push origin main --force
      env:
        REPO_KEY: ${{secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN}}
        username: github-actions
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The runner is configured by the `runs-on` for each job.

It can be a [GitHub hosted runner](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-github-hosted-runners/about-github-hosted-runners) or a [self-hosted runner](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/using-self-hosted-runners-in-a-workflow) according to your context.

**Examples with GitHub hosted runner:**

```
jobs:
  job1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      [ ... ]
  job2:
    runs-on: macos-latest
    steps:
      [ ... ]
  job3:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
      [ ... ]
```

The available GitHub runner images (with the pre-installed tools) can be found [here](https://github.com/actions/runner-images) for more details.

Be aware that each runner use a specific shell by default, for example ubuntu and macos use `bash`, where windows use `powershell`.

Therefore, in your case, you just need to update the `runs-on: macos-latest` to `runs-on: ubuntu-latest` or `runs-on: windows-latest` (supposing you want to use the latest, and not a specific version).

Note that you can also use [matrix](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-a-matrix-for-your-jobs) to run the same job on different runners if necessary (without duplicating code).

Comment: Thank You! I thought that it was more difficult than that! I will try it right away

Answer (score 0):

Shameless plug: you can try [FlyCI](https://flyci.net/)'s MacOS runners. You can get runners that are up to 2x faster and 2x more affordable than GitHub's **and** we offer M2 runners also.

Just install our GitHub app and switch the `runs-on` to one of our instances:

- M1, 4vCPU, 7GB RAM: flyci-macos-large-latest-m1
- M1, 8vCPU, 14GB RAM: flyci-macos-xlarge-latest-m1
- M2, 4vCPU, 7GB RAM: flyci-macos-large-latest-m2
- M2, 8vCPU, 14GB RAM: flyci-macos-xlarge-latest-m2